# Buscar todos los articulos de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL

```
SELECT "mrp_bom"."name" AS "NAME", "mrp_bom"."code" AS "REFERENCE"
, "product_product"."name_template" AS "PRODUCT"
, "mrp_bom"."product_qty" AS "PRODUCT QTY"
, "product_uom"."name" AS "PRODUCT UOM"
, "mrp_bom"."type" AS "BOM TYPE"
, "mrp_routing"."name" AS "ROUTING"
, "mrp_bom"."date_start" AS "VALID FROM"
, "mrp_bom"."date_stop" AS "VALID STOP"

FROM "public"."mrp_bom" AS "mrp_bom"
, "public"."product_product" AS "product_product"
, "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_1"
, "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_2"
, "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_3"
, "public"."product_uom" AS "product_uom"
, "public"."mrp_routing" AS "mrp_routing" 

WHERE "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product"."id" 
AND "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_1"."id" 
AND "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_2"."id" 
AND "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_3"."id" AND "mrp_bom"."product_uom" = "product_uom"."id" 
AND "mrp_bom"."routing_id" = "mrp_routing"."id"
```

El problema que tengo es que solo me lista los artículos que cumplen con todos los requisitos es decir todos los productos que tienen NAME; REFERENCE....

Como puedo hacer para sacar la información de los que están en blanco?

gracias!

Comment: ¡Dios mío y todas esas comillas!   ¿Podrías poner una etiqueta a tu pregunta sobre el manejador de base de datos que estás usando? Si quieres ver los valores que no cumplen la condición de juntura, puedes usar `LEFT JOIN...` y de paso cambiar tus consultas uniendo todas las tablas mediante `JOIN`, de ese modo tus consultas serán más legibles.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que esta haciendo se llama join implicito y es igual de valido, sobre todo en oracle.

Comment: podes poner sobre que motor de base de datos estas trabajando.. y de paso, probaste con Coalesce??

Comment: @gbianchi sé que es un join implícito, pero, ¿si tuviera que aplicar `LEFT JOIN` aquí, cómo lo haría?

Comment: se usa (+) del lado contrario al join que quieres..

Comment: igual aca se necesitan ver datos para entender si se soluciona con un join

Comment: ya me han respondido. Básicamente esta base de datos la he sacado con LibroOfice de una base de datos de OpenERP, no sabía de la existencia del Join.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con `LEFT JOIN`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    "mrp_bom"."name" AS "NAME",
    "mrp_bom"."code" AS "REFERENCE",
    "product_product"."name_template" AS "PRODUCT",
    "mrp_bom"."product_qty" AS "PRODUCT QTY",
    "product_uom"."name" AS "PRODUCT UOM",
    "mrp_bom"."type" AS "BOM TYPE",
    "mrp_routing"."name" AS "ROUTING",
    "mrp_bom"."date_start" AS "VALID FROM",
    "mrp_bom"."date_stop" AS "VALID STOP"
FROM
    "public"."mrp_bom" AS "mrp_bom",
LEFT JOIN "public"."product_product" AS "product_product" ON "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_1" ON  "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_1"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_2" ON "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_2"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product_product" AS "product_product_3" ON "mrp_bom"."product_id" = "product_product_3"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."product_uom" AS "product_uom" ON "mrp_bom"."product_uom" = "product_uom"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."mrp_routing" AS "mrp_routing" ON "mrp_bom"."routing_id" = "mrp_routing"."id";
```

Comment: Yeison, aprende aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: perfecto es justo lo que queria! :)